# FBJS streemPublish not working

Tags: facebook, fbjs

In my application I want post a text message in facebook wall streemPublish but it is not working, can anyone tell me what i did wrong else guide me a good working tutorial,
also the below code does not showing any error....

Here is my code ...

```
<body>
<script src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function publish() {
 FB_RequireFeatures(["Connect"], function() {
   FB.Facebook.init('113700398662301', 'xd_receiver.htm');
                FB.ensureInit(function() {

                    var message = 'this is message';

                    var action_links = [{ 'text': 'Vote for Bill The Aircraft Carrier!', 'href': 'http://spayday.factor360.com/contest.html?page=viewInd&id=48082&contestId=2'}];
                    FB.Connect.streamPublish(message, action_links, null, "Share your support for Bill The Aircraft Carrier!", callback, false, null);
                });

    function callback(post_id, exception) {
        alert('Wall Post Complete');
    }

 });
}
</script>

</body>
<p>Stream Publish Test</p>
<a href="#" onclick="publish(); return false;">Post a story</a>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks a little dated. Check this for updated info on stream publishing

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

and this for setting up your FB init.

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/525/